# Downloading images on Planet Explorer using free student account?

Tags: planet, rapideye

I am logged in to @Planet Explorer with a free student account. I performed a search using an uploaded shapefile of my AOI. I selected a 3-month mosaic to reduce the amount of cloud cover and I am satisfied with the result.

How can I now download the actual images?

There is no download button on the interface!

Answer (score 1):

You can download basemap GeoTIFF images using this application: https://www.planet.com/basemaps/.

Note that downloading will only work if your account has the right permissions. It's possible your free education account won't have the right to download basemap tiles, but if it does, this application is the way to get them.

Comment: If anyone has tested this and confirmed whether a free student account does (or doesn't) have these permission, please share that information.